# Finding the text enclosed in "{" and "}" and inserting that into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me in writing the stored procedure. Here I'm having an input like something given below.

```
{local.txt_concept_id} != "" & {local.txt_ICD_code} != "" & 
{local.txt_diagnosis_uniq_id} != "" & {local.txt_ICD_desc} != ""&
{FIND( {local.txt_ICD_code} , "asp", 0 )}!=-1&
{LEN( {local.txt_diagnosis_uniq_id})}
```

From which I want to get the text which is enclosed inside the open and close curly brace. This has to be done in SQL Server itself. So no high level language
(C#, Java, PHP).

Please Help me in having the query
Expected result table will have values like

```
local.txt_concept_id
local.txt_ICD_code
local.txt_ICD_desc
local.txt_diagnosis_uniq_id
```

Comment: Hi Sanu Antony, I'm curious: You've changed the accepted answer for the fourth or maybe fifth time already... This is OK of course... I just wonder why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2843/0)**

```
DECLARE @myString NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{local.txt_concept_id} != "" & {local.txt_ICD_code} != "" & 
{local.txt_diagnosis_uniq_id} != "" & {local.txt_ICD_desc} != ""&
{FIND( {local.txt_ICD_code} , "asp", 0 )}!=-1&
{LEN( {local.txt_diagnosis_uniq_id})}';

SELECT T2.X.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
(SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT @myString FOR XML PATH('')), '{', '<X>'), '}', '</X>') AS XML).query('.')) AS T1(X)
CROSS APPLY T1.X.nodes('/X/text()') AS T2(X);
```

You may also add `WHERE` condition for more filtering.

Comment: Its very close, I think i can get this from here
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you...

```
declare @s VARCHAR(MAX)=
'{local.txt_concept_id} != "" & {local.txt_ICD_code} != "" & 
{local.txt_diagnosis_uniq_id} != "" & {local.txt_ICD_desc} != ""&
{FIND( {local.txt_ICD_code} , "asp", 0 )}!=-1&
{LEN( {local.txt_diagnosis_uniq_id})}';

WITH DividedByAmpersand AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<root><r>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@s,'{LEN( ',''),'{FIND( ',''),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),''),'&','</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML) AsXML
)
,TheNodes AS
(
    SELECT nodes.node.query('.') AS OneNode  
    FROM DividedByAmpersand
    CROSS APPLY AsXML.nodes('/root/r') AS nodes(node)
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(thePart.content,2,CurlyClose.position-2) 
FROM TheNodes
CROSS APPLY(SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(TheNodes.OneNode.value('(/r)[1]','varchar(max)')))) AS thePart(content)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('}',thePart.content,1)) AS CurlyClose(position)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @myString NVARCHAR(max) = 
'{local.txt_concept_id} != "" FDKJFKJ TRJEHTJH TREKJTJT & {local.txt_ICD_code} != "" &  {local.txt_diagnosis_uniq_id} != "" & {local.txt_ICD_desc} != ""& {FIND( {local.txt_ICD_code} , "asp", 0 )}!=-1& {LEN( {local.txt_diagnosis_uniq_id_IN_LENGTH})}'
; 
DECLARE @i     INT, 
        @start INT, 
        @end   INT, 
        @new NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @FieldTable TABLE 
  ( 
     field_name VARCHAR(200) 
  ) 

WHILE ( Len(@myString) > 0 ) 
  BEGIN 
      SET @new = '' 

      SELECT @start = Patindex('%{%', @mystring), 
             @end = Patindex('%}%', @myString) 

      IF( @end < @start ) 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @myString = RIGHT(@myString, Len(@mystring) - 1) 
        END 
      ELSE IF ( Patindex('%}%', @myString) = 0 
            OR Patindex('%{%', @myString) = 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @myString = '' 
        END 
      ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @new = Substring(@mystring, @start, @end - @start + 1) 
            SELECT @myString = Replace(@mystring, @new, '') 
            SET @new = Reverse(Replace(@new, '}', '')) 
            SET @i = Patindex('%{%', @new) - 1  
            SET @new = Reverse(LEFT(@new, @i)) 
        END 

      IF( Len(@new) > 1 
          AND Patindex('%)%', @new) = 0 
          AND Patindex('%(%', @new) = 0 ) 
        INSERT INTO @FieldTable 
        VALUES      (@new) 
  END 

SELECT * 
FROM   @FieldTable
```

Comment: This is complex process but, this function does the exact purpose.